# Python: Understanding decorators

Tags: python

I dont understand how decorators execute. Since the decorated function is being overwritten

For the following example

```
def get_text(name):
  return "{0}".format(name)

def decorate(func):
  def func_wrapper(name):
    return "{0}".format(func(name))
  return func_wrapper
```

When the following statement will be executed, get_text will be overwritten by what the decorator returns.

```
get_text = decorate(get_text)
```

Since get_text is overwritten. How can the original get_text function run inside the returned statement from the decorator. When I do the following

```
print get_text("John")
```

Comment: Where did you get that example?

Comment: `get_text` isn't overwritten, there's just a reference pointing somewhere else now. The original function still exists.

Comment: You have a *"closure"* over `func`, which allows `func_wrapper` to continue to access the original function even once the identifier references the wrapper.

Comment: I found links and answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python which explained what you probably need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
def decorate(func):
  def func_wrapper(name):
    return "{0} decorated".format(func(name))
  return func_wrapper

@decorate
def get_text(name):
  return "{0}".format(name)

print get_text('name')
output:
>>name decorated
```